# Convert list to columns

Tags: r, list

My list consist of elements separated by `/` where only the first element contains the name `miR-`. I would to like to paste `miR` to all elements after the `/` sign and convert the list to a table or data frame where the list IDs (2869, 10527, etc) and the list elements are side-by-side.

List

```
$`2869`
[1] "miR-539/539-5p"    "miR-135ab/135a-5p"

$`10527`
 [1] "miR-128/128ab"                                                                            
 [2] "miR-129-5p/129ab-5p"                                                                      
 [3] "miR-142-3p"                                                                               
 [4] "miR-145"                                                                                  
 [5] "miR-153"                                                                                  
 [6] "miR-140/140-5p/876-3p/1244"
```

Output:

```
2869  miR-539
2869  miR-539-5p
2869  miR-135ab
2869  miR-135a-5p
10527 miR-128
10527 miR-128ab
10527 miR-129-5p
10527 miR-129ab-5p
10527 miR-142-3p
...
```

Dput example:

```
list(`6482` = c("miR-223", "miR-223", "miR-320abcd/4429", "miR-320abcd/4429", 
"miR-320abcd/4429", "miR-320abcd/4429", "miR-93/93a/105/106a/291a-3p/294/295/302abcde/372/373/428/519a/520be/520acd-3p/1378/1420ac", 
"miR-93/93a/105/106a/291a-3p/294/295/302abcde/372/373/428/519a/520be/520acd-3p/1378/1420ac", 
"miR-24/24ab/24-3p", "miR-24/24ab/24-3p", "miR-124/124ab/506", 
"miR-124/124ab/506", "miR-485-5p/1698/1703/1962", "miR-485-5p/1698/1703/1962", 
"miR-202-3p", "miR-202-3p", "miR-149", "miR-149", "miR-17/17-5p/20ab/20b-5p/93/106ab/427/518a-3p/519d", 
"miR-17/17-5p/20ab/20b-5p/93/106ab/427/518a-3p/519d", "let-7/98/4458/4500", 
"let-7/98/4458/4500", "miR-140/140-5p/876-3p/1244", "miR-140/140-5p/876-3p/1244"
), `4057` = c("miR-214/761/3619-5p", "miR-214/761/3619-5p"))
```

Comment: Can you share your list in a copy&paste-able way with `dput`?

Comment: From the duplicate link: `setNames(unlist(lst, use.names=F),rep(names(lst), lengths(lst)))`

Comment: Added a dput example

Comment: here is one way, you might be able to do it with a shorter code:

testlist <- list("2869"=c("miR-539/539-5p","miR-135ab/135a-5p"),"10527"=c("miR-128/128ab", "miR-129-5p/129ab-5p",  "miR-142-3p", "miR-145", "miR-153", "miR-140/140-5p/876-3p/1244") )

# create 2-column df ------------------------------------------------------

names(testlist)
listlengths <- lapply(testlist, length) %>% unlist(use.names = FALSE)
namescolumn <- rep(names(testlist), listlengths)
datacolumn <- unlist(testlist, use.names = FALSE)
result <- cbind(namescolumn, datacolumn) %>% as.data.frame(stringsAsFactors=F)

Comment: # split by / --------------------------------------------------------------

datasplit <- strsplit(result$datacolumn, "/")
ncols <- lapply(datasplit, length) %>% unlist()

alldata <- data.frame(matrix(NA, nrow = nrow(result), ncol= ncol.max)) 
for( i in 1:nrow(result)) {
  for( j in 1:ncols[i]) {
    alldata[i,j] <- datasplit[[i]][[j]]
  }
}

# include miR- ------------------------------------------------------------

alldata <- apply(alldata, 2, function(x) ifelse(!grepl("miR", x)&!is.na(x), paste0("mir-", x), x))
result <- cbind(result, alldata)
result

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Not sure if the question is a dupe of the link you posted. The task here is a little different I think.

Comment: @markus You're right, I didn't see the string manipulation in there.  Go ahead and post an answer if you can.  Anyway, the duplicate link does get very close to what the OP wants.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `strsplit` to, well split the strings separated by `\` and `stack` to convert the list to a dataframe. Finally use `gsub` to prefix each string with `"miR-"`.

```
df <- stack(lapply(lst, function(x) unlist(strsplit(x, split = "/"))))
df$values <- gsub("^(miR-)?(.*)", "miR-\\2", df$values)
df
#           values  ind
#1         miR-223 6482
#2         miR-223 6482
#3     miR-320abcd 6482
#4        miR-4429 6482
#5     miR-320abcd 6482
#6        miR-4429 6482
# ...
```